# MySQL prepared statement generating internal server error

Tags: php, mysql

I am using PHP and MySQL.  I have the following PHP code:

```
$stmt = $this->db_connect()->prepare(
"SELECT P.`pool_id`, P.`pool_name`, PL.`player_id`, PL.`alias`, PP.`paid` "
."FROM `pool` AS P, `player_pool` AS PP, `players` AS PL "
."WHERE P.`sponsor` = ? "
."AND P.`pool_id` = PP.`pool_id` "
."AND PP.`player_id` = PL.`player_id` "
."ORDER BY P.`pool_name`, PL.`alias`;");

echo "validated_user_id=".$_SESSION['validated_user_id'].PHP_EOL;
echo "stmt=".($stmt == null);
$stmt->bind_param("i", $_SESSION['validated_user_id']);
```

It continually returns 500 Internal Server Error.  The logs show [23-Sep-2016 00:05:06] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object.  The validated_user_id has a valid value but the $stmt variable is null.

At first I thought I was using a reserved word so I escaped everything - no success.  I have many other DB queries that look very similar that work just fine...

What really burns me is that the exact same code works fine on my local workspace - this error only appears on the host.  Thing is I haven't a clue what to look for to find out why - please help.

Found the problem - there was a very slight difference in the name of one of the columns that was not on the host.

Comment: First thing to do, print out that statement to see if it's in order.

Comment: Please refer this link http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Comment: Have a look at the version of the MySQL server both locally and on the remote host.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `prepare()` function seems to return null. This might happen due to an error in SQL, but most probably, if it works on your local machine, there is a problem with the database connection.

Check your `$this->db_connect()` function if it reports connection errors. Separating the `db_connect()` call from the `prepare()` call might help to isolate the root cause:

```
$connection = $this->db_connect();
var_dump($connection);
$stmt = $connection->prepare(...);
```

Comment: Tried this I have a connection - still fails when I try to create the statement.

Comment: You mentioned the SQL might be buggy which was in fact the case - thanks.